# Pending signals not being delivered

Tags: linux, centos, signals, signal-handling

I wrote this program to check blocking of SIGQUIT signal. The problem is after restoring to the previous state, the signal is pending but it isn't being delivered.

Here's the main program

```
sigset_t newmask, oldmask, pendmask;
if(signal(SIGQUIT,sig_quit)==SIG_ERR)   //Register signal handler
    printf("\nerror\n");
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask,SIGQUIT);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&newmask,&oldmask);   //Save previous value and block SIGQUIT 
sleep(5);
sigpending(&pendmask);
if(sigismember(&pendmask,SIGQUIT)){ //Check if SIGQUIT is pending
    printf("\nSIGQUIT pending..\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&oldmask,NULL);   //Restore old value of sigset
printf("\nSIGQUIT unblocked\n");
fflush(stdout);
sleep(5);   //Sleep again to check if everything is A-okay!
```

I can understand that in the first sleep the signal is blocked. But even after unblocking, in the second sleep function, the program isn't responding to SIGQUIT.

What could be the possible problem here?

P.S I'm using CentOs

Here's the handler function

```
void sig_quit(int i)
{
     printf("\nSIGQUIT caught\n");
     fflush(stdout);
     signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_DFL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you aren't unblocking `SIGQUIT` when you think you are:

```
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&oldmask,NULL);   //Restore old value of sigset
```

With `SIG_BLOCK`, [`sigprocmask`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sigprocmask.htm) is adding `oldmask` to the currently blocked signals.

Try instead:

```
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldmask,NULL);   //Restore old value of sigset
```

Furthermore, in `sig_quit` you are using `printf` which is not an [async-signal-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html) function. You can use, for example, `write` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I had overlooked that statement!